# Axios get request wont work but post request does?

Tags: reactjs, rest

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {



  handleSubmit(event) {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3050/login', {
      "username": "username",
      "password": "password"
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {

      return(

        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

      );
  }

}

export default App;
```

In postman, given a GET request and this input json I get below as wanted

```
{
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password"
}
```

The response body is a 200 OK and returns

```
{ 
    "friends": 0,
    "id": "555"
}
```

I get this error when I click submit on react though

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)
```

If I were to change my backend to POST and send axios.post instead it would work . I cant figure it out. Does anyone know? Is there something different you have to do to send a get request with axios?

Comment: Can you post the code for the backend route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you are sending JSON in GET request. In GET, you can send values either in path or query params. If you send in body then it wont work. 
As a best practice, if you want to send something then use POST call instead of GET.

Comment: Mine doesn't use parameters its sending in body. So sending body in GET isn't possible in js? "if you send in body then it wont work"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add query string parameters to your get requests, you need to call axios like so:

```
axios.get("http://localhost:3050/login", {
  "params": {
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password"
  }
})
```

Note that the axios.get and axios.post accept different parameters:

- `axios.get(url[, config])`
- `axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`

You can't use `.get` and `.post` interchangeably with the same parameters.

The API you're hitting may also not accept a username and password over its GET API.

Answer (score 0):

You are making an axios get request, 
There are two ways you can pass params to your request

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3050/login?username='username'&password='password')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

or you can pass params like this

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3050/login', {
  params: {
   username: "username",
   password: "password"
   }
})
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Ref: [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Hi try do it with jsonplaceholder and choose in header Json :)
And in server side `console.log(req.body)`
And for finished do `const body = username, passport` **frome state**